# Signal/Pause Deadlock

Tags: c++, linux, process, deadlock, shared-memory

I have hard time managing children processes via signals and shared-memory (I know pipes could have been better). I have the following loop of:

```
 * parent processing something, then signaling the children and going into pause,
 * children processing something, then signaling the parent and going into pause,
 * etc. etc.
```

The problem is that sometime after signaling the parent (via kill), the os switch to the parent without ever letting the child to pause(). When it resumes the child (after the parent invoke pause) the child then pauses and I have a deadlock :(.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to avoid this race, you need to block the signal you are using with `sigprocmask()`.  Then, insted of `pause()`, use `sigsuspend()` to atomically unblock the signal and suspend the process.

This will mean that if the signal is sent before the process calls `sigsuspend()`, it will not be delivered until the `sigsuspend()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to implement atomic semaphores on your own using the signaling mechanism, and as you've discovered that's not possible because you don't get the guarantees you would need for it to work.

I suggest looking into the facilities made available by the pthreads system instead, moving from a multi-process paradigm to a multi-thread paradigm instead. Failing that, you might try using the (badly aging) System V IPC mechanisms, but I think you would be much better off with pthreads.

Comment: Or more modern POSIX IPC equivalents.

Comment: It depends on the application.  IPC isn't hard to use.  There are benefits to segregating functionality to separate process and threads come with a bag of problems of their own.  Given the choice of debugging separate processes or threads the former is almost always easier.

Comment: Thanks for you comments! Unfortunately, threads are not an option for me. I'm using a large program that was designed badly using many many globals, and each instance needs its own separate memory segment. I want to manage a few instances of this program for sub-calculations and then gather the results. I have to do it efficiently, and hence I chose to use shared memory. What options do you think I should use (from POSIX IPC)?

Comment: @LironCohen: `sem_open()` / `sem_post()` / `sem_wait()` / `sem_close()` are probably what you need to co-ordinate access to the shared memory segment.